# Is the S&P500's excess return above Treasuries after investing monthly for forty years really 3.6% annualized?

Tags: investing, rate-of-return, spreadsheet, long-term, standard-and-poors-500

I was playing with Robert Shiller's [U.S. Stock Markets 1871-Present and CAPE Ratio](http://www.econ.yale.edu/~shiller/data.htm) dataset to simulate an investor who buys the S&P500 with their monthly savings—equal to that month's CPI—for the last forty years, reinvesting dividends. (I assume the existence of a zero-fee way to buy fractions of the S&P500's level.)

I calculated their internal rate of return in excess of the risk-free rate they would have gotten by investing in the ten-year Treasury note (whose rate each month is also included in the dataset; I assume the existence of some savings account that pays a monthly interest at rate equal to the ten-year T-note). I used XIRR to obtain the money-weighted annual rate of return.

The number I got was 3.59% annualized (equal to 8.23% from the S&P500 minus 4.63% from the Treasuries).

**This seems particularly low** so I'd like to ask if this matches other analyses, or if I made a mistake in my [spreadsheet on Google Sheets](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jzBiJ4OAIDo35Nom0U6a655TJAnqeoMf/view?usp=sharing) (this is the original spreadsheet from Shiller's website plus columns added to help me compute the above numbers).

---

I also wrote some open-source JavaScript code to run this same analysis, but for several forty year horizons (as well as ten, twenty, and sixty year horizons). That analysis corroborates this result, and [is also available online](https://fasiha.github.io/shiller-heat/excess-return.html).

A static snapshot of the graph it generates is below. The S&P500's excess returns over forty and sixty year horizons ending in the last several decades seems lackluster, not breaking 4% since the 1960's, and this too makes me wonder if I'm doing something wrong, or if this jibes with others' analyses.

[image: Excess return of the S&P 500 above Treasury for all 60, 40, 20, and 10 year horizons since 1871]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Self-answer—how awfully embarrassing, I had a bug in how I was handling dividends, in both

- the [Google Sheets spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jzBiJ4OAIDo35Nom0U6a655TJAnqeoMf/view?usp=sharing) and
- in [the webapp](https://fasiha.github.io/shiller-heat/excess-return.html), in JavaScript.

(I was basically not reinvesting dividends…)

With this correction, the result is better: the excess return, investing the CPI every month, over the last forty years has been 5.8%.

---

I noticed that the spreadsheet had columns for the real price and dividends (i.e., nominal price adjusted by the CPI), so using those, and investing $1 monthly, the *real* excess return of the S&P 500, over the last forty years, comes out to… **2.8%**.

I've updated both the [spreadsheet](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1jzBiJ4OAIDo35Nom0U6a655TJAnqeoMf/view?usp=sharing) and the [interactive website](https://fasiha.github.io/shiller-heat/excess-return.html) with the bugfix and to show real excess returns.

A static snapshot of the website:

[image: Fixed: investing $1 monthly in the S&P 500, real excess returns over ten, twenty, forty, and sixty year horizons]